# Calculating intersection point of two tangents on one circle?

Tags: math, geometry, raycasting

I tried using a raycasting-style function to do it but can't get any maintainable results. I'm trying to calculate the intersection between two tangents on one circle. This picture should help explain:

[image]

I've googled + searched stackoverflow about this problem but can't find anything similar to this problem. Any help?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the intersection of two lines, given their equations?

Comment: Given their equations? I guess so, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if your variables are:

```
C = (cx, cy) - Circle center
A = (x1, y1) - Tangent point 1
B = (x2, y2) - Tangent point 2
```

The lines from the circle center to the two points `A` and `B` are `CA = A - C` and `CB = B - C` respectively.

You know that a tangent is perpendicular to the line from the center. In 2D, to get a line perpendicular to a vector `(x, y)` you just take `(y, -x)` (or `(-y, x)`)

So your two (parametric) tangent lines are:

```
L1(u) = A + u * (CA.y, -CA.x)
      = (A.x + u * CA.y, A.y - u * CA.x)

L2(v) = B + v * (CB.y, -CB.x)
      = (B.x + v * CB.y, B.x - v * CB.x)
```

Then to calculate the intersection of two lines you just need to use [standard intersection tests](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Peter Alexander assumes that you know the center of the circle, which is not obvious from your figure http://oi54.tinypic.com/e6y62f.jpg.
Here is a solution without knowing the center:

The point `C` (in your figure) is the intersection of the tangent at `A(x, y)` with the line `L` perpendicular to `AB`, cutting `AB` into halves. A parametric equation for the line `L` can be derived as follows:

The middle point of `AB` is `M = ((x+x2)/2, (y+y2)/2)`, where  `B(x2, y2)`. The vector perpendicular to `AB` is `N = (y2-y, x-x2)`. The vector equation of the line `L` is hence
`L(t) = M + t N`, where t is a real number.